# How to change compiler of OpenMPI

Tags: gcc, x86-64, cross-compiling, openmpi, arm64

I have OpenMPI which is using gcc to compile. I need to cross compile from an x86_64 host architecture to an aarch64 target architecture. Instead of using gcc to compile, I want to use aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc to cross compile.

Anyone know how to change the compiler from gcc to aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OpenMPI is a library.  It doesn't compile your code using gcc, *you* compile your code using gcc or `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc`.  You presumably need an aarch64-linux build of OpenMPI to compile/link against.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. From what I found, it looks like mpicc is a compiler that by default wraps gcc. I'm looking at the link at the end of this comment. Under the sections 'Files' or 'Environment Variables', it seems that I can change the compiler that mpicc is using. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/mpicc.openmpi.1.html

Comment: Oh, right, yeah `mpicc` is a wrapper that passes the right args to whatever compiler you're using.

Comment: If I do edit those 'Files' the webpage is talking about, would that change mpicc the next time I use it? Or would I have to reconfigure or something?

Answer (score 5):

openmpi allows using their mpi-wrappers (i.e., mpicc, mpic++, ...) with a different compiler by specifying:

```
OMPI_CC=COMPILER_NAME_OR_PATH
OMPI_CXX=COMPILER_NAME_OR_PATH
```

e.g.,

```
OMPI_CC=clang
OMPI_CXX=clang++
```

or

```
OMPI_CC=/usr/bin/gcc-11
OMPI_CXX=/usr/bin/g++-11
```

In some cases, you might need to export these variables by prepending the `export` keyword.